# Mutually exclusive dices?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have 3 dice. Each has some mechanism that can prevent other dice being in 2 if itself is 2 when they are rolled together. Now I roll the 3 dice at the same time. Then what is the probability of having a 2 appearing?

Is the answer 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 = 1/2 since the event are mutually exclusive and each has a probability of 1/6?

But without the mechanism the probability of at least one 2 appearing is 1 - (5/6)^3 = 91/216 < 1/2?

Why should the probability decrease?

Comment: How does your "mechanism" not affect the probability of an individual die roll being $2$?

Comment: To make an even more absurd example, suppose you rolled $12$ dice with the mechanism.  Your computation would make the probability $2$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael So you mean because of the mechanism, the event of 2 appearing for the single die is not mutually exclusive? Then how should I calculate the probability?

Comment: It depends on  what this "mechanism" does.  If it does leave the individual probabilities at $1/6$ and makes them mutually exclusive, then your calculation was correct.

Comment: This appears to be different from the other question, since it is said that the mysterious mechanism applies to $2$, and so it is reasonable to suppose by default that it does not apply to the others. The probability of **not** getting a $2$ is as usual $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$, so the probability of getting (at least) one $2$ is the same as usual.

Comment: OP: Is this the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/915890/? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: In a comment to the earlier question, OP asked whether the answer changed if the mechanism applied only to $2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Then the probability of getting a 2 is 1/6? But then since the event is mutually exclusive, we can get 3 * 1/6 which is 1/2 for the probability?

Comment: In order to give an answer, the "multiple $2$'s not allowed needs to be made precise. I tried to make it precise, and Did correctly pointed out that under that model we get the answer $3/8$, and not $91/216$

Comment: Allitee, it seems that it's not possible to give a complete answer to this question unless you say more about the mechanism. For example, the results will be different if the mechanism deals with multiple twos by: (a) rolling all the dice again, until an acceptable combination is obtained; or (b) selects one of the two twos (or two of the three twos) at random, and rolls only those dice again, repeating the process as necessary if one or two twos are obtained again. There are other conceivable possibilities besides (a) and (b), and the results would be different again.

Comment: @Dave I actually thought the situation (b).

Comment: @Allitee, in that case, the probability of at least one two appearing will be the same as if there were no mechanism, $1 - (5/6)^3$. The reason is that although the mechanism in (b) affects the *number* of twos that appear, it doesn't affect whether there is at least one two or there is none. That remains the same as in the original roll that the mechanism "corrects."

Comment: @Dave I was confusing about the mutual exclusive property of the dice. Since they can't be two at same time, the event of one die is two is mutual exclusive to other die being two. Then should the probability of a two appear in the roll be 3*(1-5/6)?

Comment: @Allitee, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to trials without a mechanism, with mechanism (a), with mechanism (b), or with a different mechanism?

Comment: @Dave I refer to (b). At that mechanism, let the event 1 be that die 1 is at two, similarly for event 2, 3. Then P1, P2, P3 are mutually exclusive. So the probability of either of them occurring is P1 + P2 + P3 = 1/2?

Comment: In that case the probability of P1 is $(1/3)[1-(5/6)^3] = 91/648$. The same holds for P2 and P3. The reason the result is less than 1/6 is because after the first roll, if the first die is a two, there is some chance it will have to be changed by the mechanism. However, if it is not a two, it won't be changed. So the probability of obtaining a two on the first die is less than if there were no mechanism. The calculation results from the fact that P1, P2 and P3 are mutually exclusive events with identical probability, and the probability of their union is $91/216$.

Comment: I understand your reasoning. But how do you get the P1 = (1/3)[1−(5/6)^3]?

Comment: P1, P2 and P3 are mutually exclusive events. Their union is the event E = "there is a two" = "there is at least one two before the mechanism operates", whose probability is 1 - (5/6)^3 = 91/216, just as if there were no special mechanism. Since all three events P1, P2 and P3 have the same probability P(P1), we have 3P(P1) = P(P1) + P(P2) + P(P3) = P(E) = 91/216.

Comment: Allitee: Your lack of reaction to my demand for explanations is puzzling. Do you do this often?

Comment: @Did Because I thought that the comment following yours by Andre had explained it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is reasonable to suppose by default that the mysterious mechanism does not apply when a number other than $2$ is tossed.

The probability of **not** getting a $2$ is then as usual $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$, so the probability of getting (at least) one $2$ is the same as usual.

Note that the probability of *multiple* $2$'s is now $0$, so for example the probability of at least one $6$ is greater than usual.

**Remarks:** $1.$ The problem now is to produce a physically reasonable model, to put flesh on the bones of the mysterious mechanism. I have not succeeded in doing so.

One possibility that is contrary to the wording is that the dice are rolled **sequentially**. If the first toss is a $2$, the machinery kicks in, and we end up with one $2$, probability $\frac{1}{6}$. If we don't get a $2$, the probability of a $2$ on the next toss is $\frac{1}{6}$, and then the machinery kicks in and we again get a success. And of course we can have success if we get a non-$2$ twice, then a $2$. That gives probability $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5^2}{6^2}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$. That gives probability $\frac{91}{216}$.

$2.$ Below, verbatim, is my earlier (wrongly analyzed) suggestion.  The error was pointed out by Did.

We supply an explicit non-magical mechanism that satisfies the OP's condition. Toss three dice. If we get more than one $2$, toss again until we get one or fewer $2$'s. In any round of this game, the probability of getting no $2$'s is unchanged from the usual independent fair dice assumption.

Comment: The probability that the "non-magical mechanism" presented in the Remark produces $0$ twos is not $(5/6)^3$. To see why, let $p=(5/6)^3$ the probability to get $0$ twos in a toss of the three dice and $q=3(1/6)(5/6)^2$ the probability to get $1$ two in a toss of the three dice. Then, in any round of the game, the probability of getting $0$ twos is $p/(p+q)=5/8$, not $p$.

Comment: @Did I don't understand why you say the probability is not (5/6)^3 and then let p = (5/6)^3 where p is the probability of get 0 twos.

Comment: @Allitee This p is the probability to get 0 two when one throws three dice once. The procedure suggested in the answer was to throw the three dices anew when one got more than 1 two, until one got 0 or 1 two. The probability to get 0 two when one stops *this procedure* is indeed p/(p+q).

Comment: @AndréNicolas You suppressed the paragraph explaining a so-called non-magical procedure. Let me suggest to restore this paragraph, first because it describes an interesting mistake, second because without it my comment debunking it becomes difficult to understand.

Comment: I will restore it, it will indeed be useful.

Comment: Then can I say the probability of getting 1 two is 1 - p = 1/6? But then will the probability becomes 3 * 1/6 since the event that one die is two is mutually exclusive to other dice getting a two?

Comment: I have added a (not persuasive) model under which the probability is $\frac{91}{216}$.

Answer (score 1):

If the mechanism only applies to 2, then they are just like ordinary dice until a 2 appears.  Hence the probability of no 2s in three rolls is still $\left(\frac56\right)^3$.  So the probability of at least one 2 in three rolls is $\frac{91}{216}$ just like ordinary dice.

Comment: Then the probability of getting a 2 is 1/6? But then since the event is mutually exclusive, we can get 3 * 1/6 which is 1/2 for the probability?

Comment: @Allitee: Actually the probability of a 2 on roll 2 is $\frac16\cdot 0+\frac56\cdot \frac 16 = \frac{5}{36}$ (because in the case that the first die was 2, the second die has $0$ probability of coming up $2$).  Similar reasoning leads to the probability of the third die being 2 is $\frac{25}{216}$.  The three events are mutually exclusive, and so the probability of a 2 is $\frac16+\frac{5}{36}+\frac{25}{216}=\frac{91}{216}$.

Answer (score 0):

Due to this mechanism, there's only two possibilities for how many twos appear. Either no twos appear or one two appears. Let $A$ be the event that no twos appear. Let $B$ be the event that one two appears.

So $P(B) = 1-P(A)$.

Since $P(A) = {125 \over 216}$,

$P(B) = 1 - {125 \over 216} = {91 \over 216}$.

The trick is to disregard events where more than one two appears since that is impossible in this scenario.